# Picture Box size expanded when program runs

Tags: c#, webcam, qr-code, picturebox

i am currently learning on  webcam based qr code decoder i have taken an example from https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/AForgeDemo/ . i have manage to get it working however i have a problem which baffle me. it is regarding to the picture box in my GUI.

[image]

the image above is before i press the start/ continue button. the image after is as below

[image]

is there any setting in the picture box property which could prevent the picturebox from expanding or do i need to type a source code to. it would be great if anyone could highlight what i need to do to prevent the expending of the picture box. thank you

Comment: Set MaximumSize to the size you have originally set in the design mode.

Comment: yes mr hjalmar Z. trying it now

Comment: It will probably fix the borders but only show a portion of the image. See if you can change the output on your webcam if that's the case.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so that you can close the question. Edit: I might have jumped to conclution early, that is if my suggestion was the one that made it work ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `MaximumSize` property of the picture box to however big you want it to be. You can also set `MinimumSize` while you're at it.

Comment: i just change the value at the picturebox property Maximum size. i haven't try to see if it show the whole portion of the image or only half. if it shows only half, i will update Sir. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try This Code on click of Start Button

```
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Set the SizeMode property to the StretchImage value.  This 
// will enlarge the image as needed to fit into 
// the PictureBox.
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
```

Hope it will helps you

Comment: Mr Neeraj, it doesnt work. it stil expands as i run my webcam

Comment: hai mr neeraj, it solved by changing the MaximumSize at picturebox property

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to set PictureBox.SizeMode to everithing else than AutoSize.

Comment: This was my first thought as well, turns out the `PictureBox` control doesn't have an `AutoSize` option.